# Map a json element with a property without using JsonPropertyName attribute

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I am working with `System.Text.Json` and need to map some elements of the json result with the properties of my entity. Some of these elements have the underscore character to separate words while my properties are in case pascal. I know I can use the `JsonPropertyName` attribute to map the json element to my property, but I'm looking for a way to do this without using the `JsonPropertyName` attribute.

Comment: You could decompile the attribute (either the System.Text.Json or the NewtonSoft one) and figure out how they do it. But, why bother, you have two pieces of paper you wand to permanently attach and a stapler in your hand, just use it.

Comment: I am using .NET 7.

Comment: @Flydog57 - the requirement seems reasonable.  It's often the case that some type which needs to be serialized is in an external library and can't be customized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom naming policy with a serializer.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new UnderscoreNamingPolicy()
};

var jsonString = "{\"first_name\":\"John\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\"}";

var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(jsonString, options);
```

And define the naming conversation according to your underscore logic. (code provided below may not be precise to your use case as you didn't specify the casing besides the underscores, but you should be able to build on top of it)

```
public class UnderscoreNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        bool capitalizeNext = false;

        foreach (var c in name)
        {
            if (c == '_')
            {
                capitalizeNext = true;
            }
            else if (capitalizeNext)
            {
                sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
                capitalizeNext = false;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to bind all Pascal-cased .NET properties to [snake_cased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) JSON properties, you can use the [`PropertyNamingPolicy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy) shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144162/3744182) by [Levan Goderdzishvili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635476/levan-goderdzishvili).

If, as stated in the question, you need to *map **some** elements of the json result*, in **.NET 7 and later** you may use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to customize your type's [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts).

First, define the following static method returning an `Action<JsonTypeInfo>`:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> RemapNames(Type type, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> names)
    {
        // Snapshot the incoming map
        var dictionary = names.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value).AsReadOnly();
        return typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object || !type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
                return;
            foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                if (property.GetMemberName() is {} memberName && dictionary.TryGetValue(memberName, out var jsonName))
                    property.Name = jsonName;
        };
    }

    public static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}
```

And now if you have a model that looks like e.g.:

```
public class Model
{
    public string PascalCaseProperty { get; set; } = "";
    public string SnakeCaseProperty { get; set; } = "";
}
```

You will be able to serialize `SnakeCaseProperty` as `"snake_case_property"` as by customizing a [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver) as follows:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    [nameof(Model.SnakeCaseProperty)] = "snake_case_property",
};
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.RemapNames(typeof(Model), dictionary) },
    },
    // Add other options as required:
    //PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    //WriteIndented = true,
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
```

E.g. for `Model` the resulting JSON will look like:

```json
{
  "PascalCaseProperty": "PascalCase Value",
  "snake_case_property": "snake_case value"
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AYtigt).