# How to ignore JsonPropertyName in serialization using System.Text.Json in .Net 6

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am using `System.Text.Json` in .NET 6 and I have some data classes that have properties annotated with `JsonPropertyName` to be able to communicate with another API, but now I need to use the original properties names for another business reason and was looking for a way to make the serializer ignore those annotations and use the actual property names.
I've found that in Newtonsoft I could've used `ContractResolver` to do it like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622492/how-to-ignore-jsonpropertypropertyname-somename-when-serializing-json), but I couldn't find an alternative in `System.Text.Json`.
Now I am thinking of using DTOs to do it but I am looking for a simpler solution if it's available.

Here's a quick example, say we have this `Account` class:

```
public class Account {
    [JsonPropertyName("fname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("lname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("years_old")]
    public int Age {get; set; }
}
```

In one use I want the response sent to be of the format:

```json
{
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "years_old": 25
}
```

And in another response, I need:

```json
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "age": 25
}
```

Now this is just a sample, but my actual classes have a lot of properties, and making DTOs isn't for each use case is too much work. Hence why I am looking for a solution using something like Newtonsoft `DefaultContractResolver` but using `System.Text.Json`.

PS: I can't afford to move back to Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Just remove JsonPropertyName  from your properties

Comment: @Serge I explicitly said that I needed those for other requests, so removing them isn't really an option. I was looking for some way to disable them for a given serialization.

Comment: Your question is not clear. There are two operations - serialization and deserialization. What do you need what for?

Comment: The class is used in communication with 2 different APIs, where in one it needs to use properties names defined using the `JsonPropertyName`, whilst the other requires the actual properties names. Something like what's required in the question I linked.

Comment: Data from API usually needs to be deserialized only. In any case it is getting even more confused now.

Comment: I made an edit, I hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: I think it's better to create two classes of Account, with fields that API's required. And then implement some basic logic to clone/copy one class to another if needed. If it's different API's with a different fields names, at one point you will require to pass some additional field to one of them, but not for another.

Comment: In .NET 7 MSFT introduced `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` which is equivalent to `DefaultContractResolver`, see [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74284215/3744182).  You could cancel the `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` using that.  See e.g. [Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250152/3744182).  But in .NET 6 your options are much more limited.  Can you more to .NET 7?

Comment: @dbc I reached the same conclusion too in my research, before deciding on doing anything I thought I'd ask here to check if there is maybe some way to do it in .NET 6 but sadly there doesn't seem to be any.

Comment: There's nothing easy.  Obviously you could create your own custom converter that cycles through the properties and serializes each one using reflection.

Comment: I would consider using different DTOs for different APIs.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use a mapper and dto, the only way I see ( and I think it is more effective)

```
    var origJson = @"{
    ""fname"": ""John"",
    ""lname"": ""Doe"",
    ""years_old"": 25
}";

    var fixedJson = FixPropertyNames(origJson);

public string FixPropertyNames(string json)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(json);

    sb.Replace("\"fname\"", "\"firstname\"");
    sb.Replace("\"lname\"", "\"lastname\"");
    sb.Replace("\"years_old\"", "\"age\"");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

or if your classes are small, you can remove a string builder and put all code in one line.

```
fixedJson= origJson.Replace("\"fname\"", "\"firstname\"").Replace("\"lname\"", "\"lastname\"").Replace("\"years_old\"", "\"age\"");
```

And I guess your API should return a content, since you have created a json string already

```
 return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```