# Unable to deserialize complex object using private accessor

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, system.text.json

I am trying to perform a simple transformation from one json property to another. I have a model with some properties as follows:

```
[JsonPropertyName("incomingPropName")]
public MyComplexObject[] Prop1 { private get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("transformedPropName")]
public MyComplexObject[] Prop2 { get => Prop1; }
```

I would like to transform *incomingPropName* to *transformedPropName*. Specifically, I want to deserialize a json string with a value for Prop1, set the value for *Prop1* to *Prop2*, and ignore *Prop1* during serialization. This works perfectly with string data type, but not with custom object array. Is there a way to make this work?

I know it's not an issue with the model because I am able to deserialize the object without trying to do the transformation.

I have a working solution by implementing IJsonOnDeserialized interface, but this is not my first choice and I'm not looking for alternative solutions. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "I have a working solution " what are you looking for than?  Why your question is called unable to deserialize? Show the json string and code you have tried so far and tell us what is your problem

Comment: @Serge - the question is clear.  They are trying to deserialize JSON with a property that has one name, and serialize that property to JSON with a different name.  They are trying to do it with a publicly set-only property for deserialization and a get-only surrogate property for serialization (a common trick with Newtonsoft).  It is working when the property is a string, but failing when the property is an array, and they would like to know why, and whether this is possible in general.  What more is needed?

Comment: @dbc  "I have a working solution .... but this is not my first choice and I'm not looking for alternative solutions" What is this about? Why are you always trying to  answer the sloppy questsions where OP doesn't understand what he wants and is to lazy to put any expanations

Answer (score 0):

You can force a public property with a non-public setter or getter like `Prop1` to be serialized and deserialized by marking it with [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-7-0#non-public-property-accessors).  But since you only want it to be **deserialized**, you could convert it to a surrogate for some backing field, return `null` from the getter, and mark it as ignored when returning null:

```
public class Model
{
    MyComplexObject[] prop = Array.Empty<MyComplexObject>();
    
    [JsonPropertyName("incomingPropName")]
     // Include in serialization & deserialization
    [JsonInclude]
    // But suppress serialization by ignoring null values, then returning a null from the getter:
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public MyComplexObject[] Prop1 { private get => null!; set => prop = value; }

    [JsonPropertyName("transformedPropName")]
    public MyComplexObject[] Prop2 { get => prop; }
}
```

Notes:

- I was able to confirm your result that, in .NET 7, System.Text.Json behaves inconsistently for string-valued and array-valued properties with private setters, see my [working string demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kEFhOP) and [failing array demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JGfAsj).

  You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aarea-System.Text.Json) to MSFT about the inconsistency, as there does not seem to be any documented reason for this behavior.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tu06vl).

**As an alternative**, rather than complicating your data model by using multiple surrogate properties, you could adopt the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250283/3744182) to *[Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250152/3744182)* and use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to customize your type's [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) when deserializing.

First, copy `JsonAlternativeNameAttributeBase` and `JsonExtensions.UseAternameNames()` from that answer:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = true)]
public abstract class JsonAlternativeNameAttributeBase : System.Attribute
{
    public JsonAlternativeNameAttributeBase(string? name) => this.Name = name;
    public string? Name { get; private set; } // Use null to fall back to member name.
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> UseAternameNames<TAttribute>() where TAttribute : JsonAlternativeNameAttributeBase =>
        static typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;
            foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
            {
                if (property.AttributeProvider?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true) is {} list && list.Length > 0)
                    property.Name = list.OfType<TAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? property.GetMemberName() ?? property.Name;
            }
        };

    public static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}
```

Next define your model as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("transformedPropName")]
    [DeserializedJsonPropertyNameAttribute("incomingPropName")]
    public MyComplexObject[] Prop { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DeserializedJsonPropertyNameAttribute : JsonAlternativeNameAttributeBase
{
    public DeserializedJsonPropertyNameAttribute(string name) : base(name) {}
}
```

And now when you deserialize, use the typeinfo modifier `JsonExtensions.UseAternameNames<DeserializedJsonPropertyNameAttribute>()` to rename `Prop` to `incomingPropName` e.g. like so:

```
var json = 
    """
    {
        "incomingPropName":[{"Value" : "value 1"}, {"Value" : "value 2"}]
    }
    """;

var inputOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.UseAternameNames<DeserializedJsonPropertyNameAttribute>() },
    },
};
        
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(json, inputOptions);

var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);

Console.WriteLine(newJson); // Outputs {"transformedPropName":[{"Value":"value 1"},{"Value":"value 2"}]}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3Mlhr).