# Change property names conditionally during serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, jsonserializer, json-serialization

I have model classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

These classes are returned as result from two controllers: `XController` and `YController`.

When returning these classes as result from `YController`, default serialization is to be used.

When returning these classes as result from `XController`, two properties of `ClassA` should be renamed (no change to the types or how the values are output) and one property of `ClassB` needs to be renamed (same as before). `XController` only has `GET` calls, so doesn't need to handle custom de-serialization. Using `JsonPropertyName` doesn't meet this requirement.

How can I do this?

I followed [Using multiple JSON serialization settings in ASP.NET Core](https://thomaslevesque.com/2022/09/19/using-multiple-json-serialization-settings-in-aspnet-core/) to add a custom `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` (called `ExternalJsonOutputFormatter` (for outputting JSON to be used by "external" clients)). However, I can't see where and how I can customize the names of specific properties. My guess is I have to override `WriteAsync(...)` method, but don't know what to do in there (e.g., how low-level do I have to go to achieve what I want?).

Even links to online examples could be handy (I couldn't find anything that would show me what I need).

I would highly prefer to stick to `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: This seems like a *lot* of work that could be more easily accomplished by simply having a controller-specific projection - which could be as simple as `return new { obj.NoChangeHere, NewName = obj.OldName, ... }` etc...?

Comment: @MarcGravell That's an interesting idea. How do I achieve the `obj.NoChangeHere` part? Do I have to manually list all the (many) properties of the model (which may increase in the future) that I don't want to change or is there a smarter way to do it? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "do I have to manually list all the (many) properties of the model (which may increase in the future) that I don't want to change" - yes, otherwise they'll be omitted; note: this is just one of many ways, but: it is a common one

Comment: @markvgti - how complex are the classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`?  Complex enough that using a DTO (either an explicit type or an anonymous type as suggested by Marc Gravell) is not realistic?

Comment: If creating a DTO is not realistic, in your custom per-controller settings you can use a TypeInfoResolver with a custom [modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers) that renames properties selectively.  For an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250283/3744182) to [Asymmetric Field Names for serialisation and deserialisation using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250152/3744182).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc The classes aren't very complex as of now, although `ClassB` has 30+ properties and will change and grow. I'd thought of DTO-as-a-delegate or even an interface which does nothing but rename x number of properties, but in both I have to do manual code maintenance. Ideally looking for a solution where I can add/remove properties to the model classes w/o having to do anything specific. Unless, I want to rename a property explicitly.

Comment: @markvgti - then it seems like a custom JsonTypeInfo modifier like the one in the linked answer should work for you.  Agree?  If so, do you need a specific answer, or is the linked answer close enough to be a duplicate?  E.g. the linked answer uses custom attributes applied to the model, you might prefer to use a dictionary specified somewhere in your controller.

Comment: @dbc The answer you pointed me to seems like a good idea (thanks!). However, I am not sure how to tie that in to the framework: unlike the example, I am not explicitly serializing the results of calling an endpoint, it's being handled by the framework. So now I have to search how to make corresponding changes in ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Comment: @markvgti - the article you found "Using multiple JSON serialization settings in ASP.NET Core" shows how to create customized settings per controller.  Are you using that?  If so, for the controller where you want custom names, add settings with a `TypeInfoResolver` with the necessary resolver. If not, did you have some trouble with implementing Thomas Levesque's article?

Answer (score 0):

As a placeholder I've implemented the following solution (since I needed a solution fast), though I'd prefer a better, more standardized way of doing this, so looking forward to the answers.

I already had a utility method that takes an `object` and converts it into an equivalent `IDictionary<string, object?>`:

```
public static IDictionary<string, object?> ToDictionary(object obj,
        ISet<string>? propertiesToIgnore = null)
```

When returned as a result of an endpoint call, the serialization is exactly as expected (think about it: the simplest & most direct representation of JSON in C# is `IDictionary<string, object?>`, possibly contained within an `IList`).

I created an attribute `DictionaryPropertyNameAttribute` (analogous to `JsonPropertyNameAttribute`) which can be used to supply custom names. The difference is, while `JsonPropertyNameAttribute`, once set, will always be applied, I added a `bool` to my `ToDictionary` call to allow the method caller to turn on/off the renaming:

```
    public static IDictionary<string, object?> ToDictionary(object obj,
        ISet<string>? propertiesToIgnore = null, bool useCustomNames = false)
```

The `useCustomNames` is `false` by default for backwards compatibility.

This solution works, though, as mentioned previously, I'm open to other, better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The article to which you linked, [Using multiple JSON serialization settings in ASP.NET Core](https://thomaslevesque.com/2022/09/19/using-multiple-json-serialization-settings-in-aspnet-core/) by Thomas Levesque, allows you to introduce "named" serializer options, then apply them to selected controllers via a custom attribute that specifies the option's name.

**Assuming you implemented the code from that article**, if you modify `XController` as follows:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public const string XOptionsName = "XOptions";
}

[JsonSettingsName(JsonExtensions.XOptionsName )]
public class XController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetClassA")]
    public ClassA GetClassA() { return new ClassA { }; }

    [HttpGet("GetClassB")]
    public ClassB GetClassB() { return new ClassB { }; }
}
```

You should be able to apply custom `JsonSerializerOptions` to any controller marked with `[JsonSettingsName(JsonExtensions.XOptionsName )]` as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // Add your default options here
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(JsonOptions.XOptionsName, options =>
    {
        // Add the options required by XController here.
    });
```

**Having done that**, you can add in attribute-based alternate JSON property names.  First introduce the following custom attribute and [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers)

```
public sealed class JsonAlternatePropertyNameAttribute : JsonAttribute
{
    public JsonAlternatePropertyNameAttribute(string name, string settingsName) => (this.Name, this.SettingsName) = (name, settingsName);
    public string Name { get; }
    public string SettingsName { get; }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> UseAlternateNames(string settingsName) => typeInfo =>
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            if (property.AttributeProvider?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonAlternatePropertyNameAttribute), true) is {} list)
                foreach (JsonAlternatePropertyNameAttribute attr in list)
                    if (attr.SettingsName == settingsName)
                        property.Name = attr.Name;
        }
    };
}
```

Next, modify `ClassA` and `ClassB` by adding `JsonAlternatePropertyNameAttribute` to the properties that should be conditionally renamed when serializing with the `"XOptions"` settings:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } = ""; // Roughly 30 of these
    
    [JsonAlternatePropertyName("AlternateName1", JsonExtensions.XOptionsName)]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    [JsonAlternatePropertyName("AlternateName2", JsonExtensions.XOptionsName)]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } = ""; // Roughly 30 of these

    [JsonAlternatePropertyName("AlternateName3", JsonExtensions.XOptionsName)]
    public string Property3{ get; set; }
    [JsonAlternatePropertyName("AlternateName4", JsonExtensions.XOptionsName)]
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, update your builder code to invoke the typeInfo modifier for controllers marked with `[JsonSettingsName(JsonExtensions.XOptionsName )]`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // Add your default options here
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(/*JsonExtensions.XOptionsName,*/ options =>
    {
        // Add the options required by XController here.
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = (options.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver ?? new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver())
            .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.UseAlternateNames(JsonExtensions.XOptionsName));
        // Add anything else you want here, e.g.
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });
```

With all that done, the relevant properties of `ClassA` and `ClassB` should be renamed when returned from controllers (or methods) marked with Thomas Levesque's attribute, and not otherwise.